# Apply multiple search exclusions in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a few hundred lines of code like this to check 
(just as an example):

```
q_Var1_q = "Hello, "
q_Var2_q = "World!"

msgbox q_Var1_q & q_Var2_q
```

I want to check if I haven't forgot to type `_` inside each `_q`. 
I.e., if I'll find something like `q_Var1q` (instead of `q_Var1_q`) 
— that would be a "typo" to edit.

Therefore, I need to find `any words` ending with `q`, 
**except** if they have a `_` right before that `q`.

I tried `[^_]q` in <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> (with "Regular expression" checked), and it worked, 
but I got too many results because it also finds a `q` in the beginning of each variable. 
So I tried several other options, like `([^ ]q)([^_]q)` and `[^ ]q|[^_]q`, 
but I've left with no idea on how to apply multiple exclusions properly.

I.e., if everything is fine 
— **I want to find nothing**; and if there is at least 1 "typo" 
— I want to find all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this search string, based on yours : `[^_]q[^\w]`

It looks for "not-underscore, q, not-word-character".

It will also find a single `q`, which I hope you don't have.